# Loop to return an array when row number and array number does not match. Problems with nested loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a problem where I have created an Array with variables and I  want to enter the values in my Array in a separate column which does not match the row index of my Array.

I want to loop through a column and I want to return a value from an Array which does not correspend with the row index of the column. That could for example be to return the first value of my Array on the sixth row.

I Think that my problem probably lies in that I don't know how to set up the nested loop.

Many thanks for any help

I have created my Array like this

```
Sub arraytest()
    Dim MonthArray() As String
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim StartRow As Byte
    StartRow = 2
    Dim r As Byte

    Lastrow = Range("B" & StartRow).CurrentRegion.Rows.count

    If Lastrow > 0 Then
        ReDim MonthArray(StartRow To Lastrow)
        For r = StartRow To Lastrow
            MonthArray(r) = Range("C" & r).Value
        Next r
    End If

End Sub
```

So if I have the values in my Array

```
MonthArray()
    Month 1
    Month 2
    Month 3
    Month 4
    Month 5
    Month 6
```

Then a simple loop without taking into account row index would be

```
For i = StartRow To Lastrow

If (Cells(i, "A").Value = "USA:" or Cells(i, "A").Value = "EU:") Then _
    Cells(i, "B").Value = " " Else Cells(i, "B").Value = MonthArray(i)  <<<
Next i
```

This would return a table in this order

```
1     USA:
2     Data  MonthArray(2)
3     Data  MonthArray(3)
4     EU:
5     Data  MonthArray(5)
6     Data  MonthArray(6)
```

But I need the array to be returned like this:

```
1     USA:
2     Data  MonthArray(1)
3     Data  MonthArray(2)
4     EU:
5     Data  MonthArray(3)
6     Data  MonthArray(4)
```

So, in this case, I want to add the value from my Array if the value in the A column is not USA or EU

What I have tried is this

```
r = 1 
For i = StartRow To Lastrow 
If (Cells(i, "A").Value = "USA" or Cells(i, "A").Value = "EU") Then _
    Cells   (i, "B").Value = " " Next i Else Cells(i, "B").Value = MonthArray (r) <<<
    r = r + 1
Next i
```

However, I want

```
r = r + 1
```

To occur only if (Cells(i, "A").Value = "USA" or Cells(i, "A").Value = "EU")

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: It sounds like you just want a multi-line if statement. Try removing the underscore at the end of the if line, and putting `End If` on a new line below `r = r + 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a contiguous range for your MonthArray, don't worry about looping and just use:

```
Dim MonthArray() As Variant, StartRow as Long, LastRow as Long
StartRow = 2
Lastrow = Cells(StartRow, "B").CurrentRegion.Rows.count
MonthArray = Range(Cells(StartRow, "C"), Cells(LastRow, "C")).Value
```

Then we move into using the array, like your code indicates:

```
Dim r as Long, i as Long
r = 1 
For i = StartRow To Lastrow 
    If UCase(Cells(i, "A").Value) = "USA" or UCase(Cells(i, "A").Value) = "EU" Then
        Cells(i, "B").Value = " " 
    Else 
        Cells(i, "B").Value = MonthArray(r,1)
        r = r + 1
    End If
Next i
```

Need your r = r+1 in the loop as you move down.

---

**Edit1:**

Make sure to add in Sheet references.  Assumption made from my testing, where I don' want to be overwriting my cells in B if I determine `LastRow` based on col B, e.g.:

```
With Sheets("MonthSource")
    Dim MonthArray() As Variant, StartRow as Long, LastRow as Long
    StartRow = 2
    Lastrow = .Cells(StartRow, "B").CurrentRegion.Rows.count
    MonthArray = .Range(.Cells(StartRow, "C"), .Cells(LastRow, "C")).Value
End With
With Sheets("Destination")
    Dim r as Long, i as Long
    r = 1 
    For i = StartRow To Lastrow 
        If UCase(.Cells(i, "A").Value) = "USA" or UCase(.Cells(i, "A").Value) = "EU" Then
            .Cells(i, "B").Value = " " 
        Else 
            .Cells(i, "B").Value = MonthArray(r,1)
            r = r + 1
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works fine. So the problem was that I didn't set up the loop properly. Also thanks for reminding about Always add Sheet references.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MonthArray() As Variant
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, r As Long

    'Always fully qualify workbook and worksheet you're working with, change this as necessary
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    StartRow = 2
    LastRow = ws.Cells(StartRow, "B").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    'Load the values of column C into an array directly, no loop required
    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(StartRow, "C"), ws.Cells(LastRow, "C"))
        If .Row < StartRow Then Exit Sub    'No data
        If .Cells.Count = 1 Then
            'Only a single value found in column C, force array type by manually redimming and adding the value
            ReDim MonthArray(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            MonthArray(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            'Multiple values found in column C, can insert values into array directly
            MonthArray = .Value
        End If
    End With

    'Initialize your array index counter variable at 0 to start
    r = 0

    'Begin loop of rows
    For i = StartRow To LastRow
        'Check contents of column A
        Select Case UCase(Trim(ws.Cells(i, "A").Value))
            Case "USA:", "EU:"
                'do nothing

            Case Else
                'increase array index counter variable
                r = r + 1

                'Output the appropriate array value to column B
                ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = MonthArray(r, 1)

        End Select
    Next i  'advance row counter

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the early catch on mine (the `r`).  Had posted untested and had a few other catches when I tried executing (e.g., added in `UCase()`), which I corrected in the edit.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also why is it so important to always qualify workbook and worksheet? Is that because the code is easier the write since you can take advantage of the with property? I just started programming in VBA 2 months ago and come from a statistics background where I've only used R and SAS before so VBA is quite new to me.

Comment: @AndreasHild The reason to always fully qualify workbook and worksheet is that a single macro can access and alter multiple workbooks and/or worksheets.  If you don't qualify, the macro will assume you want the currently active workbook and worksheet which may not be accurate and can lead to incorrect results.  Getting in the habit of always qualifying will prevent that issue and make debugging easier.